# I have an external HDD (passport) which I comfortably use in my Windows 10 but I am not able to open it in my Linux system, Why?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

I have an external HDD (passport) which I comfortably use in my Windows 10 but I am not able to open it in my Linux system, why ? I am new to the Linux system so do not have any idea, can someone help/assist ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you share a bit more info about your setup? Can you edit your question and post the output of `dmesg` when you connect the drive? `sudo fdisk -l` and `mount` will help, too.

Comment: Windows 10 uses fast start up which is just hibernation. But it also sets hibernation flag on all NTFS partitions. So is Windows 10 using fast start up? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions And more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 0):

Keep the file system healthy. Most likely, your USB drive has been formatted in the MS Windows file system, ntfs. Have the drive checked using the Windows drive checking tools. After that, Ubuntu will most likely readily mount it for you to use.

If you do not have a Windows system, and there is no reason for you to keep it in the ntfs format, then reformat it to the native linux file system ext4. If however you do not have Windows but need to keep it in the ntfs format (for example, I do not have MS Windows, but I need the drive formatted in ntfs for use on a smart TV), then you may still fix your file system in Ubuntu with the `ntfsfix` command.

To use the `ntfsfix` command, you must know the device name of your partition. You can find the device name as the first item in the row representing your partition in the output of `lsblk -f`. The option -f provides also information on the file system. This may make it easier to recognize your partition in the list. Precede the name with `/dev/` to obtain the full device name. For example, if you recognize your ntfs partition is named as sdc1, then the full device name will be `/dev/sdc1`. You can then check and repair that drive with the command:

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdc1`

Note: The ntfs file system is proprietary to Microsoft. Whereas the `ntfsfix` tool can fix basic inconsistencies, only the MS Windows tools now the full ins and outs of the file system. By preference, check and repair an ntfs formatted partition in MS Windows.